# problema con setResult(1, intent) me retorna otro valor

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estoy mandando yamar a un activity desde un fragment para procesar una informacion pero cuando me retorna el resultado en el resultCode del onActivityResult me retorna valores al azar, ¡¿a que se debe esto?

este es el codigo que estoy utilizando:

```
            Intent intento = new Intent(getActivity(), SegundoActivity.class);
            Bundle manejadordp = new Bundle();
            ArrayList<String> Al_DP_Data = new ArrayList<String>();
            Al_DP_Data.add("PERAS");
            Al_DP_Data.add("MANZANAS");
            Al_DP_Data.add("GATOS");
            Al_DP_Data.add("PERROS");

            manejadordp.putStringArrayList("data", Al_DP_Data);
            manejadordp.putString("Titulo", "Titulo que tendra el Activity");
            intento.putExtras(manejadordp);
            startActivityForResult(intento, CODIGO_SOLICITUD);//CODIGO_SOLICITUD=1
```

En el segundo activity:

```
 //obtengo los valores del fragment anterior
    Bundle manejadord = getIntent().getExtras();
    Data = manejadord.getStringArrayList("data");
    Titulo.setText(manejadord.getString("Titulo","Seleccione una opcion")); //Poceso informacion .....
  btnCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Buscador.getWindowToken(), 0);
            setResult(RESULTADO_CANCEL);//RESULTADO_CANCEL = 0
            finish();//finishing activity
        }
    });
  btnAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Buscador.getWindowToken(), 0);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("Opcion", "PERRO");
            setResult(RESULTADO_OK, intent);//RESULTADO_OK=1
            finish();//finishing activity
        }
    });
```

pero como pueden ver en la siguiente imagen me retorna otro valor diferente en el resultCode al que yo le estableci en el setResult 
[image: imagen del resultado]

a que se debe esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que obtener el mismo intent con el que lanzaste la actividad. Lo tienes que obtener en la actividad lanzada.

```
btnAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Buscador.getWindowToken(), 0);
        // Intent intent = new Intent();
        Intent intent = getIntent(); // obtienes el intent que lanzo la actividad.
        intent.putExtra("Opcion", "PERRO");
        setResult(RESULTADO_OK, intent);//RESULTADO_OK=1
        finish();//finishing activity
    }
});
```